# Styling bootstrap themed checkbox with label on single line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to utilize the bootstrap "form-control" class on a checkbox within a label tag so that clicking the text also checks the textbox.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vpm13m2b/

The HTML for the control is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        Attempt #1
        <span class="red">*</span>
    </div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" /> Yes
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        Attempt #2
        <span class="red">*</span>
    </div>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" /> Yes
    </label>
</div>
```

With attempt 1, the "Yes" text is pushed to a separate line. With attempt 2, the checkbox and underlying controls are pulled the width of the page, which also pushes the "Yes" text to the second line. The screenshot of this is below:

[image: broken screenshot]

Here's what I am trying to do:

- The styled checkbox is displayed next to the "Yes"
- Selecting the text also selects the checkbox
- Keep the solution clean (trying to avoid dealing with `float:left` or jquery click events on the text to check the checkbox)

It just seems that there has to be a vanilla way to do this. All the bootstrap docs just show standard checkboxes - nothing with the `form-control` class styling the checkbox for their nice inline examples.

Comment: Are you wanting the label to the left or the right of the checkbox ?

Comment: Text would be to the right of the textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with to fix my issue. I need to retain the .form-control class on the checkbox element so that the checkbox control is styled by the bootstrap theme. My busines requirement is to use the themed, not default browser, checkbox.

See working JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vpm13m2b/3/

```
input[type=checkbox].form-control {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: -8px;
}
```

The css above was added into my site's stylesheet so that the form-control checkboxes retain the style, and I don't have to change the existing code that has a label containing the checkbox and caption to the right of the checkbox vertically centered.

This works with my original attempt (#1) on the html below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        Attempt #1
        <span class="red">*</span>
    </div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" /> Yes
    </label>
</div>
```

The resulting output matches what I'm looking for in the original question:

[image: Screenshot of solution]

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `class="form-control"` from your checkboxes. As the bootstrap docs state:

> All textual `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` elements with
>   .form-control are set to width: 100%; by default.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vpm13m2b/1/)**

The .form-control class has about a dozen properties being set that you most likely don't want or need.

Comment: But the form-control class is what enables the checkbox to be styled in the theme.

Comment: You can write any styles you like for it without having to add that class. You can see in the examples that none of the checkbox examples have that class.

Comment: But as my requirements state, I need the styled checkbox working with the theme, and I'm trying not to go too far off creating my own UI here (ie: parallel code that is like .form-control, but not quite). I appreciate your help. +1 for noting that .form-control styles the controls to width 100% by default - that was very helpful.